# Not able to print value due to error while connecting mongodb to qt in python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

UPDATE:

```
THIS IS THE DATA
{ "_id" : 0, "score" : 5, "name" : "tim" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e9cafc74a2c3fdf7faf2417"), "Name" : "HP" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e9cbb54451f7b5afa42588a"), "Name" : "HP" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e9cc157698d5d09e9a4ebdd"), "Name" : "HP" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e9cd9432ee5c9ebd3b9a3a3"), "Name" : "HP" }

    CODE:

            data=list(collection.find())
            result=data
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

            for row_number,row_data in enumerate(result):
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
                for col_number, data in enumerate(row_data.values()):
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number,col_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
```

Following is the output I want in organize manner now the row name & column name is missing & little unorganized pls check image below

[FINAL ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NICdf.png)

Comment: There is no `connect` method. You have a mongodb cursor with data in your `data` variable.

Comment: Okay so how can I fix it in the output I am getting row & columns printed not the values, how should i fix it?? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would convert data to a list with `data=list(connection.find())` and then replace `result` with `data` in the loop.

Comment: Hey thanks but thats not working may be i am doing it wrong,

Comment: collection=db["mycollection"]
        data = collection.find()
        data=list(collection.find())
        result= connection.connect(data)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

        for row_number,row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for col_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number,col_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

Comment: Could you do the change in code send

Comment: Please update your question and post all code in a code block. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I have done the editing please help me out

Comment: 1 - Delete/comment the first `data = collection.find()` statement. 2 - Delete/comment the `result = connection.connect(data) statement. 3 - replace the value `result` with `data` in the `for row_number, row_data in enumerate(data)` statement. These three changes work for me.

Comment: FYI - posting code good and screenshots of code bad - then the code can be copied and tested

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere It shows now:  command find requires authentication. Thanks I will follow your feedback from now but it still shows require authentication. where should i write username & password & how?

Comment: Do you know your user and password that you setup when turning on authentication to your local mongo instance? If so you can update your `MongoClient()` statement with the following - connection=pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017, username='<username>',password='<password>')

Comment: I tried still I am getting row name & column name only not the values, please help me

Comment: Well, do some debugging - put in some print statements and try changes your enumerate  statements. Maybe for your second `for` statement try `for col_number, data in enumerate(row_data.values())` and add a print statement after like `print(f'row data is {data}') - investigate the data at each step.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I did some editing in the question at top please help me out I am really close thanks again